# Run-time Complexity for two algorithms (Big O notation calculation)

Tags: python, algorithm, runtime

what is the Big O notation for that two algorithms:

```
def foo1(n):
    if n > 1:
        for i in range(int(n)):
            foo1(1)
        foo1(n / 2)

def foo2(lst1, lst2):
    i = 1
    while i < max(len(lst1), len(lst2)):
            j = 1
            while j < min(len(lst1), len(lst2)):
                j *= 2
            i *= 2
```

I thought that foo1 run time complexity is O(n) because in that case if I see the for loop I can do that:

> T(n) = O(n) + O(n/2) <= c*O(n) (c is const) for all n.

is that right ?

and I cant calculate the run time of foo2 can some one help me to know to do that.

thanks...

Comment: `foo1(n / n)` is this a mistake?

Comment: no it is foo1(n / n) = foo1(1)

Comment: So why didn't you just write it as foo1(1)?

Comment: i wrote a comment that is the the same.

Comment: ok, i change it to foo1(1)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The number of operations `T(n)` is equal to `T(n/2) + n`. Applying the [Master theorem](https://brilliant.org/wiki/master-theorem/) we get `T(n) = O(n)`. In simple terms there are `n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + 1` operations that are less than `2*n` and is `O(n)`.
2. The inner loop does not depend on the outer loop, so we can treat them independently. `T(n) = O(log(maxlen) * log(minlen))`.

Comment: I except with you in the run-time of foo2 thank you for that, it is logical here. but can you explain way you multiply T(n / 2) with 2. what is the 2 here. thanks.

Comment: @MohammadJaber, that's my mistake, I'll change the answer

Comment: ok, but thanks for you, I dont think that the Master theorem will help me here but now I learn that that it will help me in that case ... thanks